# Slight toilet wiggle after installation

Tags: bathroom

I installed a new toilet and after I finished the installation there is a slight wiggle when I grip the side to check if it will rock. It’s definitely not a rock or a wobble but the smallest wiggle. Is that ok? I don’t want to tighten the bolts anymore as I fear I might have gone too far already, though nothing cracked.

Here is what I did
- removed old toilet and wax ring. Cleaned up old wax as best as possible. 
- put new bolts in flange and placed new wax ring (standard thickness not extra thick) on bottom of new toilet bowl. 
- set new bowl in place, pressed down 
- put nuts on the bolts and tightened
- tested bowl by trying to manually wobble the bowl and noticed a small wiggle. Tightened bolts a bit more 
- assembled tank onto bowl and connected water
- turned on water, checked for water leaks from tank/bowl connection, supply line or under toilet and no water was seen.

Is it ok for a toilet to wiggle a little bit? Again it’s not rocking off the floor or even wobbling. Just need some peace of mind as I am not a plumber by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Very common this is why they make toilet shims. Loosen nuts, slip shims under toilet to make it stable. Tighten nuts. Trim away excess shim material. Then contemplate the big debate “to caulk or not to caulk”

Comment: The wiggle is so slight that I am not sure where a shim would even go.

Comment: That's why you loosen the nuts 1st.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I am just saying that the wiggle is so slight that even with loose nuts, I am not sure where I could even shim it. Will shimming cause an issue with the wax ring? I thought I shouldn’t be moving the bowl once the wax was in place.

Comment: Caulk it with silicone but leave a void on each side so yiu will know if the wax ring ever starts leaking

Comment: I found that the plastic toilet shims tend to work their way out. I like the idea of silicone caulk. This will probably take the wiggle out. If the wiggle is side to side start near the back and caulk around the front to the back on the other side. Leave a gap in the back.

Comment: Maybe it's the flange or the drainpipe wiggling? Could be more significant that the toilet rocking....you might have to pull the toilet and take care of that first, then reinstall. Could maybe screw/bolt the flange to the floor to correct it.